# Codeigniter won't autoload helpers

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, autoload, helper

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.5 and I am trying to autoload the url helper `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` and I am getting the error

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/_helper.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check if the url helper exists in /system/helpers/ ?

Comment: Not sure how we'd know if you installed CodeIgniter correctly, but I'll suggest that you re-read the documentation and make sure you've properly installed/uploaded all the system files.

Comment: system/helpers/url_helper.php does exist within the project

Comment: Hello. I have the same problem, but just on the start page.